Periodic renewal requirements for ongoing Gmail access via OAuth starting June 3, 2024
This is regarding mail received from google for subject "Periodic renewal requirements for ongoing Gmail access via OAuth starting June 3, 2024". We need to know details regarding line mentioned in mail - "Users will be able to renew or revoke this access at any time through the “Third-party apps & services'' page on My Account", Please confirm if a user renew's his access at any time through the “Third-party apps & services'' page on My Account then

Will the previous refresh token get renewed for another 6 months with same value

Or

A new refresh token will be generated with validity of 6 month.

If second point is true than what should be the procedure at application end to get that newly generated refresh token as we would be having old refresh token value.
Also as mentioned in mail "Any existing Gmail access granted to these apps will expire on July 15, 2024 unless renewed by the user." We already have approval for one-time extension request, so will all our users existing token older than 6 months expire immediately?

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

@DarkBee Google itself has mentioned in mail to raise on stackoverflow on google-oauth tag for technical support.

Can I support my product on this site? - SO is Q&A website, not a support forum by the way

This is defiantly a programing related question as it is related to how to handle developers must create their applications to support googles ever changing Oauth security requirements.


After June 3, 2024, Gmail access granted to reporting and monitoring apps will automatically expire after six months. Users must renew permissions for continued access. Unless renewed by the user, any existing Gmail access granted to these apps will expire on July 15, 2024.

It basically means that Gmail refresh tokens have a max life time of six months.  After six months the user will have to authorize your app again at which time you will again get a new refresh token.
Assuming your app is designed to handle expired refresh tokens it should not be effected by this.   Your app will just request a new one of the user next time they login.
clarification
Google will send users email reminders about upcoming access expirations in order to renew them before they expire.
Users can choose to grant ongoing access to their accounts from the Third Party Connections page and choose not to receive renewal notifications.
This option will work for single-user apps where the user might want to provide continuous access without regular renewals.

Linda what about the line where it says Users will be able to renew from Third-party apps & services page on My Account, will there be option to user to renew from there also or user will be able to renew only from my app?

Im still trying to get more info from the team on this.   they haven't documented it yet  I will get back to you when i get some clarification.

Got some clarification.
